# how to covert Symfony1.4 Doctrine:Query to Normal Mysql Query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony1

i have searched a lot about how to convert symfony doctrine query into normal mysql query for debugging purpose.

like i have in codeIgniter

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

it convert active records to mysql normal query for debugging purpose.

so my question is it possible to covert doctrine to normal query for debugging purpose in symfony 1.4 or symfony2, and what are the keywords.

my doctrine query is

```
$q_fixed = Doctrine_Query::CREATE()
                ->select('u.name')
                ->from("fields u")
                ->where("u.field_type_id=?", "1")
                ->leftJoin("u.FieldType t")
                ->leftJoin("u.FieldCategory c")
                ->groupBy("u.id");
```

how to convert it to normal mysql query?

your help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: You can log query then from logged query you can directly use that query using PDO in symfony http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/logging-doctrine-queries-in-symfony2/

Comment: actually i am using symfony1.4

Answer (score 1):

In symfony2 you can use `getSql()` on your queried object ,but for the bound parameters you will have `?` in query instead of provided parameters,it will not give you the full query with the provided parameters

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$query->select('u.name')
            ->from("fields u")
            ->where("u.field_type_id=?", "1")
            ->leftJoin("u.FieldType t")
            ->leftJoin("u.FieldCategory c")
            ->groupBy("u.id");
echo $query->getQuery()->getSql();
```

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo you can use `getQuery()->getSql()` on your queried object in symfony 1.4 too

Answer (score 0):

Just run the dev version of the controller and copy it from the debugging toolbar.

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('myapp', 'dev', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 1.4 you can use `getSqlQuery()` method of `Doctrine_Query` object. It will return sql query converted from dql. Note that it may include placeholders instead of actual values of parameters, you will need to replace the ?'s with the correct values when you execute it.